# c# - how to convert 26/Jun/2016 at 13:14 to 2016-01-26 13:14:00

Tags: c#

i wanted to convert  `26/Jun/2016 at 13:14` from a `string` to  `datetime` data type
for saving to sql

```
string DtTime = ds.Tables["VOUCHER"].Rows[0]["BASICDATETIMEOFINVOICE"].ToString();
```

how to split as a string

Comment: [Convert.ToDateTime()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/xhz1w05e(v=vs.110).aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Comment: All of these questions about converting `string` to `DateTime` and vice-versa should be merged into one answer. Without that there will still be a bunch of duplicates.

Comment: it showing error-@Tim Schmelter

Comment: @m.rogalski: maybe, but this answer would fill a book because there are many edge cases and format specifier. It should at least contain the documentation which is mainly [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings) and [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings). So i doubt that the answer would be very helpful if someone searches for help because `DateTime.ParseExact("26/Jun/2016 at 13:14", "dd/MMM/yyyy at HH:mm", null)` doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the `/` and the `at` in the format string, then you can use `ParseExact`:

```
DateTime.ParseExact("26/Jun/2016 at 13:14", "dd/MMM/yyyy 'at' HH:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings

But are you sure that the value is not stored as `DateTime`? Check by using `ds.Tables["VOUCHER"].Rows[0].Field<DateTime>("BASICDATETIMEOFINVOICE")`. Then no conversion from `Object` to `string` to `DateTime` is needed. If not you should consider to store it as `DateTime` in the first place, wherever the `DataTable` was filled from.

Comment: how to remove  escape the / and the at from this.plz help me

Comment: @fidha: i dont understand your question

Comment: string[] Date = DtTime.Split(' ');
              string[] bal = Date[0].Split('-');

              DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse(bal[0]);
              string sty = dt.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd");

              int month = dt.Month;
              string[] time = Date[2].Split(':');how can i save to a string by merging all to  "2017-09-14 02:29:29"    this formate

Comment: @fidha: why don't you use my approach?

Comment: I'd feel more comfortable with `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` instead of `null` (or is `"Jun"` always recognized as the 6th month? Assuming `null` would cause a fallback to `Current(UI)Culture`), but other than that, this works.

Comment: @corak: you're right. Then i can also remove the escape characters around `/` which is only needed if you use `CurrentCulture` (or `null`).

Comment: ... and then `ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)` (which is what OP seems to want to end up with)

Comment: thanks-@TimSchmelter

Comment: @fidha: i really don't understand your approach. If the string contains `at` then my approach works, test it with your sample string. You don't need to split it, that's very error prone. If you need the date use `dateTime.Date`. If you need the time use `dateTime.TimeOfDay`. If you need the hour use `dateTime.TimeOfDay.Hours`. If you need the minute use `dateTime.TimeOfDay.Minutes`, and so on. You see, all you need is to parse the string to `DateTime` with the correct format.

Comment: 26/Jun/2016 at 13:14 ."at" is on the xml file .i am not adding